# QTimer with asio::io_service.poll_one() or poll()

Tags: c++, qt, boost-asio, qtquick2

I am using `asio` (standalone header only) within a `Qt` Quick application.

As Qt and asio have both their own event loop if I understood correctly, I use a `QTimer` signal to call the class that holds my `asio::io_service` object.

```
QTimer *timer_io = new QTimer();
QObject::connect(timer_io, SIGNAL(timeout()), &my_INandOUT, SLOT(poll_ios()));
timer_io->start(IO_TIMER);
```

I have set IO_TIMER to 100 ms. I have read in the documentation that `asio::io_service.reset()` must be called after each `poll()`. So the slot `poll_ios()` has the following code:

```
void INandOUT::poll_ios()
{
    //    qDebug() << "poll_io signal";
    m_io_service.poll_one();
    m_io_service.reset();

}
```

Is that the correct way to call the `reset()` ? Or should I call it in each handler once they have finished their task ? Is it safe or could I loose `asio` events ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler and easier to lose the `asio` events and use `Qt` builtin classes instead: e.g: [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) or [QUdpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html).

However, calling `poll_one` or `poll` from a timer (as you have done) is the normal way of using `asio` with an external event loop.

But I don't recommend calling [reset](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) after calling `poll_one` since according to the documentation it should only be called:

> when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the
>   io_service being stopped or running out of work

If you re-enable your asio handlers (e.g. enabling a receive handler after receiving a message) then `io_service` always has work to do. In which case it would be better to just call `poll` instead of `poll_one` and lose the call to `reset`, e.g.:

```
void INandOUT::poll_ios()
{
    // qDebug() << "poll io signal";
    m_io_service.poll();
}
```

Comment: The first thing I do with `asio` is an `async_connect`, and my handler never gets back if I don't use the `m_io_service.reset()`. Thanks, I will have a look at QNetworkAccessManager.